# jcarousellite with next prev button and auto slide together

Tags: jquery, slideshow, jcarousellite

http://www.gmarwaha.com/jquery/jcarousellite/?#demo

Hi,

jcarousellite is a very nice jquery extension. I am using it for both auto slideshow and prev/next button.

However when I combine this effect like this

```
$(function () {
    $(".hd_splash").jCarouselLite({
        btnNext: ".next",
        btnPrev: ".prev",
        visible: 1,
        start: 1,
        scroll: 1,
        auto: 9000,
        speed: 1000,
        circular: false
    });
});
```

then it is giving me issue.

if autoslideshow is halfway and if I click next...then the entire slideshow slides couple of images and comes back to the image that was next.

Has any one done this before ?

Thanks .....sorry dont have online demo to show

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using Cycle plugin which gave me what I wanted.